# Why does margin 0 on the body not remove the margin on an h1 element?

Tags: html, css

As far as I know body should target all elements nested inside it. In my case it should give my h1 a margin of 0;

```
   body {
   font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

[Margin is not an automatically inherited property](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin). It needs to be specified on each individual element, including children of `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually not all properties will be inherited by inner elements.

Look for the concept of inherited and non-inherited properties:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value

Answer (score 0):

@Dave gave the answer. If you set `body {margin:0px}`, it will only make the `margin` around `body` tag `0`; Children must have their own `margin` settings. `margin` is not in the list of inherited properties.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to targel all elements try to use

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

but this will not be automatically inherited by your other elements.

Comment: What *other elements*?